# Is there any official way to get the admin options of a model?

Tags: python, django

I need to get to the `search_fields` property defined on the admin options for a model. A long time ago it was really simple and direct (but undocumented), i.e. `model._meta.admin.search_fields`.

Getting to the admin is the hard part, and the closest I could get was:

```
def admin_options(model):
    from django.contrib import admin
    return admin.site._registry.get(model)
```

I couldn't find the `._registry` member documented (and the underscore seems to imply that it isn't public).  This also doesn't work for sites that haven't run `admin.autodiscover()`. The fallback-code does this:

```
try:
    appname = model.__module__.split('.models')[0]
    admin_module = appname + '.admin'
    __import__(admin_module)  # registers admin option classes with AdminSite
except:
    return None
else:
   return admin.site._registry.get(model)
```

Is there an official (or simpler) way to get the admin options for a model?

Comment: what version Django have you used?

Comment: `AdminSite` does not contain any method that exposes `_registry`; I strongly suspect there is no official way to do this. Accessing `admin.site._registry` still feels better than your fallback, though.

Comment: @mrvol we're on Django 1.5.4 right now, but will be upgrading "very soon".

Comment: @Phillip I agree that the fallback is hacky (and I really don't know what other side-effects it causes), the problem is that `admin.site._registry` is empty if the site/project did not do a `admin.autodiscover()`.  What `admin.autodiscover()` does is to find and run all the `admin.py` files (and running them registers, ie. fills-in, `admin.site._registry`...)

Comment: admin.site._registry is not empty only after call admin.autodiscover(). So, if you want  use admin.site._registry you must call admin.autodiscover() on start if manually, for example to try to import <app_name>/admin.py and then, try to register those AdminModels to admin.site instance, by method admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)  All steps do admin.autodiscover() on start django

Comment: Continue. So you need check admin.site._registry and if it does not exist or empty, just call admin.autodiscover() manually.

Comment: @mrvol the `__import__` in my fallback code does the import of `admin.py`, but just for a single app.  Are you saying I should call `admin.autodiscover()` instead?  fwiw, this is a site that shouldn't have admin available (but I'm guessing it's ok as long as the urls are not linked in..?)

Comment: I don't know what do you what in generally. I guest,  your apps investigates others django projects and create admin for them dynamically. For that, I'd prefer to check admin.py in app's folders by `os.path.exists` and import it, and then, register by `admin.site.register` manually. In other case, if it's your application, i'd prefer call `admin.autodiscover()` with start Django (an official way)

Answer (score 3):

first create model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models
class LocationCode(models.Model):
    """
    A web service that will allow user to create there price rule based on conditions
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

in admin.py you need to add code

```
from django.contrib import admin
from dx_man.models import LocationCode 
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class LocationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=[]
    for x in LocationCode._meta.get_all_field_names():
        list_display.append(str(x))

admin.site.register(LocationCode, LocationAdmin)
```

in url.py add these line

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

Comment: Does this answer how to get model fields from the admin, or how to get a model's admin fields (my question)? -- or are you trying to say that such fields need to be defined on the model and then "imported" to the admin..?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure the registration code has been run or the site will not contain the (model, modeladmin) in the _registry.

### code.py

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import site

# run admin registration code before we get here
for model, model_admin in site._registry.items():
    if model == whatevermodel: 
        print(model_admin.search_fields)
```

Comment: Note: This was for django 1.8. I have not back tested this.

Comment: "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources."

Comment: ps: isn't your for-loop equivalent to `print (site._registry[model].search_fields)`?